# How to Read Physical path mapped with iis site or application

Tags: batch-file, iis-8, msdeploy

I am writing a batch script for deployment of web application.
I am using ms-deploy for this purpose.
Is there any way by which i can get the Physical path associates with virtual directory (SITE/Application) by command line.

Let say if user supplied Site name as argument then i have to copy certain number of file to site's physical location.

So here how i can get the site's physical path.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide an example of what you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET "AppCmd=%WinDir%\System32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe"
%AppCmd% List VDIR
```

I use the 'SET' line because there is often other info I want to get. See APPCMD /?

Comment: It will list all the VDIR along with physical path, how to get specific SITE/Application Path.